# Calculate highest temp in each month for all stations

Tags: datetime

I have data like this.

stationID   datetime    lat lon airPressure temperature humidity    windSpeed   precipitation
178 1/1/2010 0:00   -6.835777   -38.311583  984.8   28.5    64  1.6
178 1/1/2010 1:00   -6.835777   -38.311583  985.2   27.3    67  1.6
178 1/1/2010 2:00   -6.835777   -38.311583  985.5   26.4    70  3.2
178 1/1/2010 3:00   -6.835777   -38.311583  985.7   26.3    71  1.7
178 1/1/2010 4:00   -6.835777   -38.311583  985.2   25.7    76  1.1
178 1/1/2010 5:00   -6.835777   -38.311583  984.6   24.9    86  1.4
178 1/1/2010 6:00   -6.835777   -38.311583  984.1   24.2    85  0.3
178 1/1/2010 7:00   -6.835777   -38.311583  984.5   24.5    87
.......

422 31/12/2010 18:00    -20.35976   -47.77522   936 31.7    55  1.8
422 31/12/2010 19:00    -20.35976   -47.77522   935 32.2    55  1
422 31/12/2010 20:00    -20.35976   -47.77522   934.3   31.6    62  3.5
422 31/12/2010 21:00    -20.35976   -47.77522   934.7   30.3    67  1.5
422 31/12/2010 22:00    -20.35976   -47.77522   936 27.7    94  1   12.8
422 31/12/2010 23:00    -20.35976   -47.77522   936.5   22.4    95  0.9 13

How can I calculate highest temp in each month for all stations?

I guess I have to use datatime range to determine the month range first and use max to find out the highest temp in each month.

Any further tips...?

How do understand datetime index properly?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: What OS are you using?  Do you have any (computer) language requirements or expectations?